# Using setTimeout to display one image at a time

Tags: javascript, timer, hide, delay, show

I'm using a hover function with a fade in and fade out to show and hide images.  The problem is I want each image to finish fading before the other begins to fade in.

This is what I'm trying.  The setTimeout function has broke the hover function and all images are displaying when the page loads.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var delay = 0;

  //Everything below repeats for each image 

  $("#image_e_natural_minor").hide();

  $("#hover_e_natural_minor").hover(
      if (delay == 1) {
      setTimeout(function() {
      function () {
        $("#image_e_natural_minor").fadeIn(1000);
      }, //mouse over
      function () {
        $("#image_e_natural_minor").fadeOut(1000);
        delay = 0;
      } //mouse out
    );  //hover close
    },1000); // delay time
  }
  else {
  $("#hover_e_natural_minor").hover(
    function () {
      delay = 1;
      $("#image_e_natural_minor").fadeIn(1000);
    }, //mouse over
    function () {
      $("#image_e_natural_minor").fadeOut(1000);
      delay = 0;
    } //mouse out
    );  //hover close
  }
```

This is what I had before that works but it will display two images at once.

```
  $("#image_e_natural_minor").hide();
  $("#hover_e_natural_minor").hover(
    function () {
      $("#image_e_natural_minor").fadeIn(1000);
    }, //mouse over
    function () {
      $("#image_e_natural_minor").fadeOut(1000);
    } //mouse out
    );  //hover close

  $("#image_e_harmonic_minor").hide();
  $("#hover_e_harmonic_minor").hover(
    function () {
          $("#image_e_harmonic_minor").fadeIn(1000);
    }, //mouse over
    function () {
      $("#image_e_harmonic_minor").fadeOut(1000);
    } //mouse out
    ); //hover close
```

Sorry for the poor syntax.  I'm very new to programming.

Comment: Your code isn't formatted correctly. you can't pass an if statement to a function.

Comment: You've got quite a few errors... some logic, some syntactical... also, if you're repeating code for every image, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Are we just making random guesses at syntax?

Comment: Any suggestions on what I can apply to my latest posted code to prevent two images from displaying at once?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery functions [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) both have a callback param which is triggered when the animation finishes, so you can hook the `fadeIn` for current image call right when `fadeOut` finishes.

**But:** try this on a single image first; once you have it working try to rewrite it in a function you can call on every image. Remember DRY principle: Don't Repeat Yourself.

EDIT: 
What I mean is: When hover over image A 'hover detector', the function should first fadeOut the currently visible image B (which you can get using `:visible`'s jQuery selector) and when the fadeOut animation finishes it will call the fadeIn of image A (which you provided throw the callback param):

```
$("#image_e_natural_minor").hide();
$("#hover_e_natural_minor").hover(
    function () {
        $(".myImageClass:visible").fadeOut(1000, function(){$("#image_e_natural_minor").fadeIn(1000)});
    }, //mouse over
    function () {
        $("#image_e_natural_minor").fadeOut(1000);
    } //mouse out
);  //hover close
```

**Again**: try this with a single image, and then rewrite it so it looks like:

```
$("#image_e_natural_minor").hide();
$("#hover_e_natural_minor").hover(
    function(){showThis('#image_e_natural_minor')}, //mouse over
    function(){hideThis('#image_e_natural_minor')} //mouse out
);  //hover close
```

Comment: Having a single image wouldn't allow the questioner to get the desired behaviour, which is that one image doesn't fade in until they other has finished fading out. Two images maybe.

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, edited with an example. I think it will do it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Scm/28/). (In this example you also need to set the hover images to have class='hoverI'.)

```
var delayF = false,
    mouseOn = null;
function setHandlers() {
    $(".hoverI").hover(function() {
        mouseOn = $('#' + event.target.id.replace('hover_e', 'image_e'));
        if (!delayF) {
            mouseOn.fadeIn(1000);
            mouseOn = null;
        }
    }, function() {
        var image = $('#' + event.target.id.replace('hover_e', 'image_e'));
        if (mouseOn == image) mouseOn = null;
        delayF = true;
        image.fadeOut(1000, function() {
            delayF = false;
            if (mouseOn) {
                mouseOn.fadeIn(1000);
                mouseOn = null;
            }
        });
    });
}
$("#image_e_natural_minor").hide();
$("#image_e_harmonic_minor").hide();
setHandlers();​
```